# Populate a textbox based on the value of another textbox

Tags: vba, userform

I believe the issue is that Val(txtspark) is not recognized as a number.

```
Private Sub txtSpark_Change()

    If Len(txtSpark.Text) = txtSpark.MaxLength Then
        txtNote.SetFocus
    End If
   
    If Val(txtSpark) < 90 Then
        txtNote.Text = "Refill Required"
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of values should be kept in `txtSpark` text? Anyhow, please try `If CDbl(txtSpark) < 90 Then`. Supposing that its value  is composed from only number digits. If not, please clarify this aspect.

Comment: txtSpark will always contain a decimal number ie 95.8.  I tried CDBL with no success.

Comment: Please, try `CDbl(txtSpark.text)`. Even if VBA should guess what is it about...

Comment: FaneDuru, txtspark has a max value length of 4 and can be any decimal number between 10.0 and 99.9.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: In a way... I wanted to know if the value/text in discussion is something like: "max12.5",  or "12.5". If "12.5", the above suggestion should work. If not, do you receive an error? If yes, what error? If not, the problem is not the string conversion...

Comment: No luck on CDbl(txtSpark.text). should the if statement be in its own module.  CDbl(txtSpark.Text) < 90 Then produced a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238224/discussion-between-helipilot17-and-faneduru).

Comment: When stopped on error and move the cursor over `txtSpark.Text`, what does it show? If something normal, please move  it over `txtSpark.MaxLength`. What does it show? If not confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: txtSpark.text shows "" and maxlenght shows 4.  How do I share the workbook in discussion?  Interesting though, it writes to the worksheet fine aside from the Refill Required.

Comment: In this case, you firstly must condition that code part: `If txtSpark.Text = "" then Exit Sub`. how to extract a `Double` from an empty string...?

Comment: After some serious thought about what I wanted to do, the following code is perfect and works as it should.  Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: Have you tried 'debugging' your variables to see if your code does as is expected? One way is to create a dummy label and set the text of that label to the variable you want to explore, e.g. '''myLabel.text = Len(txtSpark.Text) + ”=” + txtSpark.MaxLength'''

Comment: My apologies for just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtSpark_Change()
    If Len(txtSpark.Text) = txtSpark.MaxLength Then
        If Val(txtSpark.Text) < 90 Then
            txtNote.Text = "Refill Required"
        End If
    txtNote.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: My solution with populating a textbox based on the value of another textbox was to use a nested IF statement.  While my previous attempts placed the txtspark value test in the txtnote_change event, it just didnt work.  Therefore I tested the length of the txtSpark and then tested for value < 90%.  If both conditions test true then txtNote is populated with "Refill Required" and focus is set to txtNote.

Comment: Could you edit your answer instead of posting it as a comment?